# Oracle Forms 6i Comparing Fields

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a form with two fields which are type Char 128 each i am trying to compare the contents of these fields. However i am not getting a proper comparison done. When both fields have the same data it is still saying both fields do not match.

```
Begin

IF(LTRIM(RTRIM(:field1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(:field2)))THEN
 Show_Message('Fields Match');
ELSE
 Show_Message('Fields DO NOT Match');
END IF;

End;
```

Comment: How does the content look like if you add it to the message? The semicolon was optional after ` Show_Message('Fields Match')`, wasn't it?

Comment: i am going to try it and let you know ooops i forgot the semicolon

Comment: Give a message from :field1 and :field2 before the if statement.
If the fields are empty this comparison won't work

Comment: Thats the problem there the fields were empty so oracle forms cannot compare empty fields

Comment: It can compare empty variables which will result in NULLs however for fields or form items it seems different

Comment: @nigthfox79 your comment is the answer you can add an answer to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as already stated that in Oracle NULL is not equal to NULL. In Oracle a comparison with NULL will always be false. You can work around this with using NVL but in this case I should prefer to instead use IS NULL like something like this:

```
Begin

  IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(:field1)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(:field2))) 
  OR (:field1 IS NULL AND :field2 IS NULL) THEN
   Show_Message('Fields Match');

  ELSE
   Show_Message('Fields DO NOT Match');

  END IF;

End;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the form fields are NULL, then the equality comparison won't work. You can use [nvl](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) function to substitute NULLs

```
Begin

IF(LTRIM(RTRIM(nvl(:field1,'*@#')) = LTRIM(RTRIM(nvl(:field2,'*@#'))))THEN
 Show_Message('Fields Match');
ELSE
 Show_Message('Fields DO NOT Match');
END IF;

End;
```